# Translate TextField value

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Some of my fields are stored in English in database and translated only in the client(in this case react-admin). So, how do I achieve this?
In my translations, I have entries for all possible member_category values and when displayed I want the value from the database to be translated.

```
export const MemberList = withStyles(listStyles)(({ classes, 
  permissions, ...props }) => (
    <List {...props}>
     <Datagrid rowClick="show">
       <TextField source="full_name" />
       <TextField source="email" />
       <TextField source="telephone" />
       <TextField source="member_category" />
     </Datagrid>
    </List>
));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a custom component wrapping a `FunctionField` instead of `TextField`.

Use `react-admin`'s `translate` HOC on it.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { translate, FunctionField } from 'react-admin';
import get from 'lodash/get';
const TranslateField = translate(( { translate, namespace, ...props } ) => {
    return (
        <FunctionField {...props}
            render={ (record, source) => translate(`${namespace}.${get(record, source)}`) }
        />
    )
});
TranslateField.propTypes = {
    namespace: PropTypes.string
}
TranslateField.defaultProps = {
    namespace: 'dbphrases',
};

export default TranslateField;
```

```
export const MemberList = withStyles(listStyles)(({ classes, 
  permissions, ...props }) => (
    <List {...props}>
     <Datagrid rowClick="show">
       <TextField source="full_name" />
       <TextField source="email" />
       <TextField source="telephone" />
       <TranslateField source="member_category" />
     </Datagrid>
    </List>
));
```

Then it's just a matter of loading the right translations in the right namespace in your `i18n` config. Here I put a default `dbphrases` namespace to take translations from `${locale}.dbphrases.${value}`

See [`react-admin`'s doc](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html#translating-your-own-components)